# When i was trying to install tomcat7 it shows all ready installed but when i try to start tomcat it shows not installed

Tags: tomcat7

[image]

When I was trying to install tomcat7 it shows already installed but when I try to start tomcat it shows not installed

Comment: Have you tried `sudo chkconfig --add tomcat7` and/or `sudo chkconfig tomcat7 on`?

Comment: chkconfig command is not working is there any other way ?

Comment: It depends on what you meant by _it's not working_

Comment: I figured it out, I have removed tomcat7 using purge and reinstalled it. Thank you